# CSV File read in Android Application

Tags: java, android, phonegap-plugins

I am little bit confused about reading a `CSV File`:

- I am picking a path with the help of intent
  "/file:/storage/emulated/0/Download/student.csv"
- And I use this path in this function:

  ```
  String splitBy = ",";
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
  String line;
  while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
      String[] b = line.split(splitBy);
      System.out.println(b[0]);
      Log.e("Final Val",b[0]);
  }
  br.close();
  ```

I got the following exception: `/file:/storage/emulated/0/Download/student.csv: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`
When I add this file to raw directory in Android it gives me correct data. Please help me to resolve this type of issue.

Comment: use like : Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/"+"student.csv";

Comment: do you have a read permission ? 
```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />```

Comment: from Android 6.0 (API 23), you need to require for permission runtime to read or write file. See more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your app needs permissions to access external storage. Check your manifest for

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```